# Updating code from Quirks Mode to XHTML 1.0 Strict - Where to Validate?

Tags: html, xhtml

I wrote some HTML code with out a DTD (rendered via quirks mode).  Sorry.  Now I want to have it validated in XHTML Strict 1.0 so I added the DTD tag

I've carried these steps to make the code "clean".

1. Verified proper nesting
2. Verified proper closure of tags
3. Verified proper closure of empty tags
4. Verified lower case
5. Verified single root element

Where can I go to validate the code?

Comment: Keeping in mind that this isn't a group work platform, but a Q & A platform. What is your Question?

Comment: My guess would be that your problem is related to the page height, but can you show us your CSS?

Comment: What a great quote : `I wrote some HTML code with out a DTD (rendered via quirks mode). Sorry.` +1 for making my day :D

Comment: This updated question makes no sense anymore. Please revert it to a sensible state.

Comment: -1: WTF? What is the question?

Comment: @stack.user.0: It's a synonym for the HTML 4.0 entity `&bull;` that works in many browsers, including mine. And instructing people to remove downvotes is folly: I downvoted for a reason, and now the downvote remains for a _different_ reason, because you've clearly not performed the basic _prior research_ step known as _searching the web_. Validators are VERY easy to find.

Comment: did you finally fix it...take a break from down_voting...there you go!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to validate your html, use http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to your code to valid then write for XHTML 1.1 and send as application/xhtml+xml.  Your browser will show you where the first error occurs and it will stop parsing the code at that point.